# Should gcc be able to find the headers it comes installed with?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm running into an issue that seems to be caused by gcc not finding the headers that come with it.  Not knowing much about C/GCC, I figured I'd check whether it's a safe assumption that the compiler should always be able to find those headers.  Perhaps setting -I arguments overrides this?  Or something else funky?

Original problem is at this issue in [shoes](https://github.com/shoes/shoes/issues/216#issuecomment-11750784) on github.

### Original issue

> Hi !  I've tried building on 10.8, with a non llvm gcc as stated in an
> other issue, and by tweaking a bit the rakefile to fetch the correct
> sdk in the correct place.
>
> BUT
>
> it still won't compile.
>
> Here's the beginning of the error report (it's really long)
>
> ```
>  new-host-2:shoes benjamingattet$ rake
>  gcc -I. -c -o shoes/app.o -Wall -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.0.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.0.0 -O -DRUBY_1_9 -DSHOES_QUARTZ -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -fpascal-strings -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4.1 -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -fno-common -x objective-c -fobjc-exceptions -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -arch x86_64 shoes/app.c
>  shoes/app.c:5:18: error: glib.h: No such file or directory
>  In file included from shoes/app.c:6:
>  ./shoes/app.h:13:19: error: cairo.h: No such file or directory
>  In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
>  from ./shoes/app.h:14,
>  from shoes/app.c:6:
>  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:48:21:
>  error: string.h: No such file or directory
>  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:58:21:
>  error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
>  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:61:23:
>  error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
>  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:64:20:
>  error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
>  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:65:19:
>  error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
>  In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:67,
>  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
>  from ./shoes/app.h:14,
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc has a builtin list of directories it searches. And files like `stddef.h` should be in one of these directories.  A way to get that list is to compile a file (even an empty one) with --verbose.  For instance here that gives:

```
$ touch foo.c
$ gcc --verbose -c foo.c
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i486 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/cc1 -quiet -v foo.c -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -quiet -dumpbase foo.c -mtune=generic -auxbase foo -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/cc2QEK5o.s
GNU C (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) version 4.4.3 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.4.3, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2-p1.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) version 4.4.3 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.4.3, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 2.4.2-p1.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 462394bb0ac77cba16b6fb6b32589358
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic'
 as -V -Qy -o foo.o /tmp/cc2QEK5o.s
GNU assembler version 2.20.1 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.20.1-system.20100303
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic'
```

The part which interests you is

```
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

where you can see that the builtin path has some non existing directories and then the list of existing directories for both kinds of include directives.

If gcc has been installed at another place than the one it was compiled for, it used to have problems. But ISTR that recent gcc are more robust in those situation and start with the executable path.

At least you know where gcc is looking for files, and you may try to understand why they aren't there.

Note that gcc doesn't come with a full C library, only a few headers strongly tied to the implementation like `stddef.h` and `stdarg.h` are provided.

Comment: I get similar output, but it doesn't find it in the other build.  I guess I'll try the --verbose flag on that one, and perhaps make a separate post for that situation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Those files do not come with GCC.

You appear to either be missing the relevant packages that provide those headers, such as glib2-devel and glibc-devel (or whatever package naming convention Max OS X uses) or you haven't put the headers under your `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk` directory that you're specifying with `-isysroot`

The `-isysroot` flag will prevent the compiler from looking in `/usr/include` as it normally would, so headers under there will not be found.  Are you sure you should be using `-isysroot`?  If you do need to then you'll need to take extra steps to allow headers outside that directory to be found, e.g. `-I /usr/include`

Comment: They do come with the specific GCC package I'm talking about.  I uninstalled the package and they went away, and reinstalled and they came back.  Knowing about this -isysroot flag is *very* useful, though.  Thank you.